# Excel Stored Procedure with Excel

Tags: sql, excel, excel-2007, vba

I have stored proc Im pulling in to excel but to get it to Run I have to enter my text exec roc 'Name'  I need it to be able to have someone else thats running it be able to enter a name as they refresh the data.  I dont know VBA at all and am looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question but if my assumption is correct... you want to have a cell where someone can enter some sort of name, where you can then use their input to do some other operations.

To start, you would want to grab a string variable (by grab I mean create)

Example:

```
Dim strName As String
```

Then you would want to be able to read a specific cell.... In the next example the cell will be A2

Example:

```
strName = Range("Sheet1!A2").Value
```

If you named the first sheet something different use that name.  If the user inputs a name into that cell you can then use it later to do calculations or anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using VBA code then what are you using?

If using MS Query, try changing the SQL text to

```
{CALL roc(?)}
```

and IIRC this should prompt the user to enter text for the parameter value.